# Librosa to get basic parameters of audio

Tags: python, audio, librosa

In getting basic parameters of an audio file, by Wave:

```
import wave

data = wave.open('c:\\sample.wav', mode = 'rb')
params = data.getparams()
print params
```

It returns:

```
(1, 2, 4000, 160000, 'NONE', 'not compressed')
```

That's for: nchannels=1, sampwidth=2, framerate=16000, nframes=47104, comptype='NONE', compname='not compressed

I assume Librosa has similar functions but no find-outs after searches.

Does Librosa have commands to produce similar results?

Thank you.

Comment: AFAIK, librosa itself only wraps other libs like [audioread](https://pypi.org/project/audioread/) to decode audio. librosa's focus is definitely not providing this kind of info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Librosa Core](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/core.html#) has some of the functionality you're looking for. [`librosa.core.load`](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.load.html) will load a file like `wave`, but will not give as detailed information.

```
import librosa

# Load an example file in .ogg format
fileName = librosa.util.example_audio_file()
audioData, sampleRate = librosa.load(fileName)

print(audioData)
>>> [ -4.756e-06,  -6.020e-06, ...,  -1.040e-06,   0.000e+00]

print(audioData.shape)
>>> (1355168,)

print(sampleRate)
>>> 22050
```

The shape of `audioData` will tell you the number of channels. A shape like `(n,)` is mono, and `(2, n)` is stereo. The `n` in the shape is the length of the audio in samples. If you want the length in seconds check out [`librosa.core.get_duration`](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.get_duration.html).

Like @hendrick mentions in his comment, the Librosa [advanced I/O page](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/ioformats.html) says `librosa` uses [`soundfile`](https://github.com/bastibe/PySoundFile) and [`audioread`](https://github.com/sampsyo/audioread) for audio I/O, and the `load` [source code](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/_modules/librosa/core/audio.html#load) shows it's just wrapping around those libraries.

However, there shouldn't be any issue with using `wave` for loading the audio file and `librosa` for analysis as long as you follow the [librosa API](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/). Is there a particular problem you're having, or goal you need to achieve?

Comment: thank you for the knowledge sharing. Just a matter of interest, no specific problem so far. :)

Comment: Just fyi: In v0.7 you should use `mono=False` parameter

Comment: This method requires reading the file. @MarkK is that also the case for `wave.open().getparams()`? 
Does librosa offer a way to get parameters without need to read file?

Comment: @ThiagoGouvea, reading the file looks like a usual way to get info from it. So I feel ok no matter a method reads the file or not. :)

Comment: I should have been more precise: librosa.load() seems to read the entire file content, when reading [the header should suffice to obtain the metadata](https://docs.fileformat.com/audio/wav/) you are asking for. That could make a big difference when trying to obtain only metadata for a large collection of files (which is my case, and potentially that of many coming to this page).

Comment: This will always return mono files at 22,050 Hz, regardless of the audio content on disk

Answer (score 1):

`librosa` does not have a specific function to load the metadata of an audio file as of version 0.10.1. There are a couple of functions for getting individual pieces of information, namely [`get_samplerate(path)`](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/generated/librosa.get_samplerate.html#librosa-get-samplerate) and [`get_duration(*, path, ...)`](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/generated/librosa.get_duration.html#librosa.get_duration) (which returns the duration in seconds and not in samples), but that's it.

To get the number of channels you must load the file and then inspect the shape of the audio. However, `librosa` does a lot of things under the hood when you load a file: by default, it will convert the signal to single channel and 22,050 Hz. If you want to read the file as it is stored on disk you must read it this way:

```py
import librosa as lr

audio_fp = "path/to/audio/file"
duration = lr.get_duration(path=audio_fp)
audio, sr = lr.load(audio_fp, sr=None, mono=False, duration=0.01)
# n_samples is approximate, but should be correct most of the times
n_samples = int(round(duration * sr))
if audio.ndim == 1:
  channels = 1
else:
  channels = audio.shape[0]
```

The `duration` keyword asks librosa to read only the first 0.01 seconds of the audio, which is enough to find out the number of channels. This can enormously speed up the process, especially when you are dealing with long files.

Some `%timeit` magic shows that the wave method takes ~26 us, while the librosa stack takes ~99 us. Not using the duration keyword on a 60-minute track requires ~221 ms (that's milliseconds, not microseconds — more than a thousand times slower). An advantage of librosa is that it can transparently deal with encoded files such as mp3 and flac with only a minor hit in performance (~125 us).